# Run void method in background

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I want to run a method in background using rxjava. I don't care about the result.

```
void myHeavyMethod() { (...) }
```

So far the only solution I have is to modify the return type to e.g. `boolean`.

```
boolean myHeavyMethod() { (...) return true; }
```

Afterwards I run:

```
Completable.defer(() -> Completable.fromCallable(this::myHeavyMethod))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(
                () -> {},
                throwable -> Log.e(TAG, throwable.getMessage(), throwable)
        );
```

Is there a way to do it keeping the `void` return type?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The [`fromAction()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromAction(io.reactivex.functions.Action)) method is what you're looking for.

```
Completable.fromAction(this::myHeavyMethod)
```

Comment: I get an error "Method reference not supported at this language level"

Comment: Method references are a Java 8 feature. So you're maybe using Java 7 and thus you have to implement the `Action` interface yourself.

Comment: don't forget to call `.subscribe()`